# How to return max occurrence of letter in string in JavaScript if we found duplicate max occurrence?

Tags: javascript

I need to return maximum occurrence of letter in string. I have written the but it's working partially. I mean maximum occurrence of letter appear more than once then it's showing only for 1 letter.

```
function maxChar(str) {
  let obj = {};
  for (let char of str) {
    !obj[char] ? (obj[char] = 1) : obj[char]++;
  }
  console.log("==obj", obj);
  let maxChar = "";
  let count = 0;
  for (let char in obj) {
    if (obj[char] >= count) {
      count = obj[char];
      maxChar = char;
    }
  }

  console.log(`${maxChar} appear ${count} times`);
}

maxChar("aabbc");
```

i am getting value in console "b appear 2 times". But actually i need to show in console "a & b appear 2 times".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When searching for the chars with maximum occurence, you have to distinguish between two differt cases:

1. The character you are looking at occurs as many times as the current maximum. Then you have to add it to a list of current maxchars.
2. The character you are looking at occurs more often as than the current maximum. Then you have to clear the list of current maxchars and add only the current char to that list.

```js
let maxchars = [];
for (let char in obj) {
  if (obj[char] > count) {
    count = obj[char];
    maxchars = [char];
  } 
  else if (obj[char] == count) {
    maxchars.push(char);
  }
}

console.log(`${maxchars.join(' & ')} appear ${count} times`);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain an array of characters instead:

```js
function maxChar(str) {
    let obj = {};
    for (let char of str) {
        !obj[char] ? (obj[char] = 1) : obj[char]++;
    }
    console.log("==obj", obj);
    let maxChars = [];
    let count = 0;
    for (let char in obj) {
        if (obj[char] >= count) {
            if (obj[char] > count) {
                maxChars = [char];
            } else {
                maxChars.push(char);
            }
            count = obj[char];
        }
    }

    console.log(`${maxChars.join(" & ")} appear ${count} times`);
}

maxChar("aabbc");
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can get the `char array` from input string using `String.split('')` method.
- And from that array, you can get the duplicated count of each letter using `Array.reduce` method.
- From that duplicated info, you can get the max count and show letters using `Math.max` & `Array.forEach`.

```js
function maxChar(str) {
  const charArr = str.split('');
  const letterInfo = charArr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    if (acc[cur] == null) {
      acc[cur] = 1;
    } else {
      acc[cur] ++;
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
  const maxCount = Math.max(...Object.values(letterInfo));
  
  Object.entries(letterInfo).forEach(([letter, count]) => {
    if (count === maxCount) {
      console.log(`${letter} appear ${count} times`);
    }
  });
}

maxChar("aabbc");
```

Answer (score 0):

I just change something in your code and it worked. Hope it can help you

```
function maxChar(str) {
  let obj = {};
  for (let char of str) {
    !obj[char] ? (obj[char] = 1) : obj[char]++;
  }
  console.log('==obj', obj);
  let maxChar = '';
  let count = 0;
  for (let char in obj) {
    if (obj[char] > count) {
      count = obj[char];
      maxChar = char;
    } else if (obj[char] === count) {
      maxChar = `${maxChar} & ${char}`;
    }
  }

  console.log(`${maxChar} appear ${count} times`);
}

maxChar('aabbc');
```